# xtensor : How to write an vector to an array

Tags: python, c++, numpy, xtensor

What is the equivalent in [xtensor](https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor) or the most optimized way to write a vector to an array.

Thanks

```py
import numpy as np

array = np.zeros((4, 4))

array[0] = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]) # this
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is

```cpp
#include <xtensor/xtensor.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xarray.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xview.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xio.hpp>

int main()
{
    xt::xtensor<double, 2> array = xt::xtensor<double>({4, 4});
    xt::xtensor<double, 1> row = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    xt::view(array, 0) = row;

    return 0;
}
```

You can use `xt::xarray` for flexibility, but it is less efficient.